# Excluding Rows when Auto Sorting

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that contains 8 sheets that needs data to be sorted upon entry. I have been able to modify a script to auto sort each individual sheet, but I need to exclude Rows 1 and 2 from the sort. I am fairly new to using scripts so any help is appreciated. Basically, as data is entered onto a Master Sheet it is sent to the Events Pages (Event 1-Event 8). From the pages I would like the data to be sorted by Column A, but exclude Rows 1 and 2.

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
var sheetNames = ["Event 1", "Event 2", "Event 3", "Event 4", "Event 5", 
"Event 6", "Event 7", "Event 8"];

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 
sheet.getLastColumn());
range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
});
```

I would like each sheet to auto sort Column 1, but exclude the first two rows. I have been able to get most of the script to work, but cannot figure out how to exclude Rows 1 and 2.

My result with this script is that each sheet will sort, but it includes the first two rows

Comment: You probably want to add some tags to this question (other than sorting). People won't see it otherwise.

Comment: You've tagged Excel. You need to tag Google Sheets instead. They're not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

- When you want to sort rows excluded row 1 and row 2 of each column by Column (A), the range is `getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())`.

  - In the case of `getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())`, only row 1 is excluded.

So can you try the following modification?

#### From :

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

#### To :

```
var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

#### Reference :

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.